# Unable to get the canonical Fitnesse example to run - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: fitnesse

This test is from the Fitnesse user guide.

```
!path /Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/bin/myPackage
!path /Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/src/myPackage
!path /Users/mpalanisamy/Downloads/fitnesse-standalone.jar
!path /Users/mpalanisamy/Downloads/FitNesseRoot
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}

!|DivisionFixture|
|num|denom|quotient()|
|1|2|0.5|
|1|2|0.6|
|4|2|2.0|
```

And the system-under-test, and fixture code is as follows - 
Division.java

```
package myPackage;

public class Division {

    private double numerator;
    private double denominator;

    public Division(double a, double b){
        this.numerator = a;
        this.denominator = b;
    }

    public double divide(){
        return this.numerator / this.denominator;
    }
}
```

DivisionFixture.java

```
package myPackage;

import myPackage.Division;

public class DivisionFixture extends fit.ColumnFixture{
    public double num, denom;

    private Division d = new Division(num, denom);

    public double quotient(){
        return d.divide();
    }
}
```

/Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/bin/myPackage - contains my .class files
/Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/src/myPackage - contains my .java files

When I run this test, I get the following error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DivisionFixture (wrong name: myPackage/DivisionFixture)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at fit.FixtureLoader.loadFixtureClass(FixtureLoader.java:66)
    at fit.FixtureLoader.instantiateFixture(FixtureLoader.java:59)
    at fit.FixtureLoader.instantiateFirstValidFixtureClass(FixtureLoader.java:82)
    at fit.FixtureLoader.disgraceThenLoad(FixtureLoader.java:43)
    at fit.Fixture.loadFixture(Fixture.java:142)
    at fit.Fixture.getLinkedFixtureWithArgs(Fixture.java:134)
    at fit.Fixture.doTables(Fixture.java:79)
    at fit.FitServer.process(FitServer.java:81)
    at fit.FitServer.run(FitServer.java:56)
    at fit.FitServer.main(FitServer.java:41)
```

The execution log has this -

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/mpalanisamy/Downloads/fitnesse-standalone.jar:/Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/bin/myPackage:/Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/src/myPackage:/Users/mpalanisamy/Downloads/fitnesse-standalone.jar:/Users/mpalanisamy/Downloads/FitNesseRoot fit.FitServer my_mac.local 53339 3863
```

- which tells me that my classpath is right, or that Fitnesse is aware of it.

FWIW, all files have rwxr-xr-x permissions.

Given the above, why do I get the NoClassDefFoundError error?

I have scoured through StackOverflow and incorporated most of the fixes, and still not able to get this simple example to run. Given the nature of the error, I am thinking the solution is something silly on my part, and / or related to configuration.

A screenshot of what I am seeing, in case that is helpful - 
[image: fitnesse error]

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be classpath, as the error indicated.

I had to change the classpath to the following -

```
!path /Users/mpalanisamy/learningfitnesse/myProject/bin
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
```

And change the first line of my test table to -

```
!|myPackage.DivisionFixture|
```

Comment: That's just how Java class loading works. You indicate the directory containing the class files, and inside that directory a subdirectory level is required for each package level. So if the code for the class states it is in `package myPackage`, the class file needs to be in the myPackage directory below the directory you specify as class path.

Comment: @FriedHoeben - Thanks. Removed my commentary about the classpath. Your explanation is helpful.